# ASP.NET Membership - keep users to use previous passwords

Tags: asp.net, passwords, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I created a Membership login system for my client, now they do NOT want the user to use one of his 5 last passwords when it comes time to create a new one.

Is that something that is build in or how could I accomplish that?

Comment: When the system is designed like this I just change my password to 'hunter3', 'hunter4', 'hunter5', 'hunter6', 'hunter7' then back to '\*\*\*\*\*\*' again.

Answer (score 4):

This feature doesn't exist on asp.net membership login system.
You must implement it by yourself, on the automatic-creating page of changing password.

You need somewhere to save the previous hash list of your users passwords, and check this list, just before accepting a password change.

## Update

**Where to start:**
Start from the all ready existing password change control.

Here is a password change example.
http://www.asp.net/cssadapters/Membership/ChangePassword.aspx

In this control, (that you can easy drag and drop on your page) capture the events,

```
<asp:ChangePassword ID="ChangePassword1" runat="server"    
 onchangingpassword="ChangePassword1_ChangingPassword" ... >...
```

Make your function to check for old passwords

```
 protected void ChangePassword1_ChangingPassword(object sender, LoginCancelEventArgs e)
 {
  if (PasswordFoundOnList())
  {
   ... show an error....
   e.Cancel = true;
  }
}
```

Now save somewhere the last passwords, for example you can saved them on user profile, or on your database.

here are some more informations for user profile.
http://www.asp.net/Learn/Ajax/tutorial-03-cs.aspx

Hope this help you make it.

Comment: Thank you for your help, do you happen to know if anyone has done that before, maybe have some code samples.  I am not sure how this would work.

Comment: Thank you very much Aristos. Since the password is encrypted in the database I was wondering how I can get it into another table and later on on compare them to a new password that the user types in. I guess I have to compare them in clear txt? 

Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Steve The password is not keepet/exist at all, only the hash value of it, so you compare the hash values, not the passwords. so you save and keep the hash values of the pass. Play a little with the GetHash of a string to see what I mean. How ever passwords did not use the same hash

Comment: @Aristos - I must not be doing something right because the 2 hashes are never equal. I made sure that the pwd I pull from the DB is the same that I am testing with. What am I missing?
MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser();
String ProviderVar = "AspNetSqlProvider2";
String UsrName = user.ToString();
MembershipProvider mp = Membership.Providers[ProviderVar];
string HashVar = mp.GetHashCode().ToString();
string pwd = "test44";
string Hash2 = pwd.GetHashCode().ToString();
TextBox1.Text = HashVar.ToString();
TextBox2.Text = Hash2.ToString();

Comment: @Steve I check now inside and see that use the MembershipProvider.EncodePassword(string pass, int passwordFormat, string salt), (not the GetHasCode()).
Now I must go - create a new question and hopefully some answer sooner than me. Ask witch way you can encode the password before saved on asp.net membership, and get the encode result.

Comment: Because the password is hashed and a slat is used, I have no idea how to start comparing what the user is entering to what I have in the table. Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: @Steve Make a question not here, no one read this, make the question globally.

Answer (score 0):

Check this awesome post by Ronan Moriarty:

[Implementing Password History using a Custom Membership Provider](http://ronanmoriarty.wordpress.com/2012/03/14/implementing-password-history-using-a-custom-membership-provider/)

It's an extensive post and I used option 2 as he describes. It has helped me implement what you ask. It's working great here.

Comment: That link is dead :(